# Hashcat passwordcracking separator unmatched

Tags: password-cracking, md5, hashcat

I have the task to crack a bunch of passwords like:

- $1$V5l3qvml$Q.fDn30gGhjcEIZH8utah/
- $1$DcuX.dRK$bR4utyGQ4ET4sobpMMtfo0
- $1$WbXWIqFu$Qu1fT/MmTIvSUz4xw4mlI0
- $1$8Y7TfkZ5$LnuF99mgFbV1wvQ61dMZB1

I was only told that these were Linux-like encrypted (I have removed the username: from the front, e.g. `sBerhhard:` and `::1:0:1:1:::` from the end). I have read [here](http://www.slashroot.in/how-are-passwords-stored-linux-understanding-hashing-shadow-utils) that these are shadow style password hashes. Furthermore, I have tried to use **hashcat 0.49** to crack these passwords. However, when trying the following command I got the following result and I cannot figure out why:

```
hashcat-cli64 -m 10 -o found.txt ..\..\1 dictionaries\Top10000.dic
```

[image]

I have also tried the example from [here](http://hashcat.net/forum/thread-103.html), and it worked, so I probably have an error in the command.

[image]

I am using the dictionary of **InsidePro**. Am I using the right m parameter (md5($pass.$salt))? If not, what would be the proper one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe those hashes are  MD5(Unix) format, so -m500.
You can compare your hashes to the ones here: [hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes](http://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes).

By the way, $1$DcuX.dRK$bR4utyGQ4ET4sobpMMtfo0:bb

Comment: Thank you for the link. However, I don't quite understand why :bb at the end. I have stated in my post that I have removed ::1:0:1:1::: from the end of each of the passwords.

Comment: When I tested to make sure I had the right format I put the hashes into hashcat and it cracked one with a password of bb, so I posted it in the hash:plain format.